# JUnit 5 + Cucumber parallel test execution doesn't work with filesafe (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

Good day. I can't execute my test in parallel threads.
My Runner:

```
package parallel;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCucumberIT {

}
```

My POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>petstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>

                            </goals>
                            <configuration>

                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                                </includes>

                                <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
                                <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                                <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>

                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm use `mvn failsafe:integration-test` command to start tests. But all tests run in the same thread.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:petstore >------------------------
[INFO] Building petstore 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (default-cli) @ petstore ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running parallel.RunCucumberIT
Thread ID -  1 - Scenario Outline Row 1 from scenario-outlines feature file.
Thread ID -  1 - Scenario Outline Row 2 from scenario-outlines feature file.
Thread ID -  1 - Scenario 1 from scenarios feature file.
Thread ID -  1 - Scenario 2 from scenarios feature file.
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.198 s - in parallel.RunCucumberIT
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.419 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-17T19:32:29+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is my steps definitions:

```
package parallel;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

public class StepDefs {

    @Given("Step from {string} in {string} feature file")
    public void step(String scenario, String file) {
        System.out.format("Thread ID - %2d - %s from %s feature file.\n",
                Thread.currentThread().getId(), scenario,file);
    }

}
```

This is my feature files
The first:

```
    Feature: Scenarios feature file

  Scenario: Scenario Number One
    Given Step from 'Scenario 1' in 'scenarios' feature file

  Scenario: Scenario Number Two
    Given Step from 'Scenario 2' in 'scenarios' feature file
```

And the second:

```
    Feature: Scenario Outlines feature file

  Scenario Outline: <scen_out_row_num>
    Given Step from '<scen_out_row_num>' in 'scenario-outlines' feature file

    Examples:
      | scen_out_row_num       |
      | Scenario Outline Row 1 |
      | Scenario Outline Row 2 |
```

I tried to use "mvn clean verify" command, but it runs all test runners even those doesn't meet "**/*IT.java" pattern (And he does it consistently)
I couldn't find any working solutions for this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your test is marked with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` which is JUnit 4 and not JUnit Jupiter which means the test will run via vintage engine and so there is no support for paralllization of tests... you have to change your code to JUnit Jupiter instead ...

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine

Comment: @M.P. Korstanje , thanks, it works. But command "mvn failsafe:integration-test" return results `[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0` , in spite of fact proper finishing of tests `Thread ID - 16 - Scenario 2 from scenarios feature file.
Thread ID - 19 - Scenario 1 from scenarios feature file.
Thread ID - 18 - Scenario Outline Row 1 from scenario-outlines feature file.
Thread ID - 17 - Scenario Outline Row 2 from scenario-outlines feature file.`

Comment: Sounds like a potential maven issue. What happens if you use the JUnit ConsoleLauncher?

Comment: I guess the zero tests is due to the parallel execution. What happens if you disable parallelism? I am reworking Surefire and Failsafe plugins and the ambition is to have better reporters - console and XML.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that mixing `junit 5`, `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` and `maven-failsafe-plugin` requires `maven-failsafe-plugin 2.22.2`, otherwise tests will be run but won't be captured, resulting in `[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`. This is both true for single threaded and parallel execution.

It seems `maven-failsafe-plugin v3.0.0-Mx` has some kind of problem capturing the tests run.